# S3 bucket policy: allow full access to a bucket and all its objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like a bucket policy that allows access to all objects in the bucket, and to do operations on the bucket itself like listing objects.  (Action is `s3:*`.)

I was able to solve this by using two distinct resource names: one for `arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*` and one for `arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket`.

Is there a better way to do this - is there a way to specify a resource identifier that refers to the bucket itself and all its contained objects, in one shot?

Comment: Nope, the way you are doing it is the way it has to be done.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Permissions against the Bucket are separate to permissions against Objects within the Bucket. Therefore, you must grant permissions to both.

Fortunately, you can write a shorter version to combine bucket-level and object-level permissions:

```
{
  "Id": "BucketPolicy",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllAccess",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
         "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
         "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
      ],
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Principal

Comment: @patrickdavey A Bucket Policy (on the S3 bucket itself) requires a `Principal`. However, if you are putting the policy on an IAM User or IAM Group, then it should _not_ have a `Principal` (since the Principal is automatically set to the IAM User/IAM Group on which the policy is placed).

Answer (score 3):

AWS has updated how it lets you enter Bucket Policy on the permissions page. I used the provided UI layer to add Action and resources. Use the below-mentioned policy and change the resource according to your bucket

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "your_arn/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If AWS changed the distinction between permissions on bucket and objects within bucket, please share a link to the documentation

Comment: @wrschneider probably my answer didn't clear it properly. They haven't changed the distinction but the UI view of how we used to enter those JSON objects of permissions.